# How to use ConcurrentHashMap in a MultiThread application with Callable

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to have a threading application and I use Callable interface, but I want all the threads to add simultaneously in a ConcurrentHashmap some values, and at the end of the program to print the hashmap with the results.
More specifically, I have a list with some names. I iterate through the list and combine threading and in each thread if the name's length is shorter than 5 , then I want it added to the concurrent hashmap.
At the end of the program I want to print the concurrent hashmap with all the names that are shorter than 5.

So my main class is the following:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class AddElementsToMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("Dimitrios");
        list.add("Maria");
        list.add("Jason");
        list.add("Io");
        list.add("Jessica");

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        ArrayList<Future<Object>> futureList = new ArrayList<Future<Object>>();

        for (String name : list) {

            Future future = executor.submit(new AddElementsToMapCallable(name, map));
            futureList.add(future);

        }

        executor.shutdown();

        System.out.println("MAP " + map);

    }

}
```

and My Callable is the following

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class AddElementsToMapCallable implements Callable {

    private String name;
    private String className;
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> map;

    public AddElementsToMapCallable(String name, ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> map) {

        this.className = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
        this.name = name;
        this.map = map;
    }

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        System.out.println(
                className + "call" + " ThreadID = " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " Processing User = " + name);
        if (name.length() <= 5) {
            System.out.println(className + "call" + " ThreadID = " + Thread.currentThread().getId()
                    + " Processing User = " + name + "length is smaller than 5. Adding!");

            map.put(name, String.valueOf(name.length()));
        } else {
            System.out.println(className + "call" + " ThreadID = " + Thread.currentThread().getId()
                    + " Processing User = " + name + "length is BIGGER than 5");

        }

        return map;
    }

    public long getThreadId() {
        return Thread.currentThread().getId();
    }

    public Thread getThread() {
        return Thread.currentThread();
    }
}
```

but what I get as a result is as you can see not what I wanted...

```
 MAP {}
    AddElementsToMapCallablecall ThreadID = 14 Processing User = Maria
    AddElementsToMapCallablecall ThreadID = 13 Processing User = Dimitrios
    AddElementsToMapCallablecall ThreadID = 15 Processing User = Jason
    AddElementsToMapCallablecall ThreadID = 14 Processing User = Marialength is smaller than 5. Adding!
    AddElementsToMapCallablecall ThreadID = 13 Processing User = Dimitrioslength is BIGGER than 5
    AddElementsToMapCallablecall ThreadID = 15 Processing User = Jasonlength is smaller than 5. Adding!
    AddElementsToMapCallablecall ThreadID = 15 Processing User = Io
    AddElementsToMapCallablecall ThreadID = 15 Processing User = Iolength is smaller than 5. Adding!
    AddElementsToMapCallablecall ThreadID = 15 Processing User = Jessica

AddElementsToMapCallablecall ThreadID = 15 Processing User = Jessicalength is BIGGER than 5
```

Could someone help me? What am I doing wrong??
Thanks !

Comment: Add `executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);` just after `executor.shutdown();`

Comment: @VictorGubin it did not work... just printed the empty concurrenthashmap at the end

Comment: There seems to be an overshadowing of `map` variable in the `call` method, try to comment out the first line on `call` method. and maybe wait until all Futures are finished before shutdown in the `main` function `try {
            for (Future f : futureList) {
                f.get();
            }
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }`

Comment: @Jhilton  yes indeed !!! thank you. If you want write it as a response so I can mark your answer right thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope issue of `map` variable passed in the constructor and the first line of method `call`. If you want to add the entries into the Map passed in the constructor you can try something like this:

```java
public class AddElementsToMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("Dimitrios");
        list.add("Maria");
        list.add("Jason");
        list.add("Io");
        list.add("Jessica");

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        ArrayList<Future<Object>> futureList = new ArrayList<Future<Object>>();

        for (String name : list) {

            Future future = executor.submit(new AddElementsToMapCallable(name, map));
            futureList.add(future);

        }

        // Wait until all threads are finished (Hopefully this is jsut for a learning experience)
        try {
            for (Future f : futureList) {
                f.get();
            }
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }

        executor.shutdown();

        System.out.println("MAP " + map);

    }


    static class AddElementsToMapCallable implements Callable {

        private String name;
        private String className;
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> map;

        public AddElementsToMapCallable(String name, ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> map) {

            this.className = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
            this.name = name;
            this.map = map;
        }

        @Override
        public Object call() throws Exception {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); // REMOVE this line. This map will shadow the map passed in the constructor
            
            System.out.println(
                  className + "call" + " ThreadID = " + Thread.currentThread().getId()
                        + " Processing User = " + name);
            if (name.length() <= 5) {
                System.out.println(
                      className + "call" + " ThreadID = " + Thread.currentThread().getId()
                            + " Processing User = " + name + "length is smaller than 5. Adding!");

                map.put(name, String.valueOf(name.length()));
            } else {
                System.out.println(
                      className + "call" + " ThreadID = " + Thread.currentThread().getId()
                            + " Processing User = " + name + "length is BIGGER than 5");

            }

            return map;
        }

        public long getThreadId() {
            return Thread.currentThread().getId();
        }

        public Thread getThread() {
            return Thread.currentThread();
        }
    }
}
```